# Flutter, Inside streambuilder, how to get stream based on a future?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want a column of posts from my firebase collection based on tags that are above a certain value. Since my values are nested in a seperate collection and document, I need to wait for a future before returning my stream.

---

### Posts[collection] -> post[document] -> tags[collection]->tag[document] -> value[field]

---

Code doesnt really work at all but what i'm trying to do is something like this:

```
StreamBuilder(

              stream:

              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").snapshots().where((post) {

                return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts")
        .doc(post.id).collection("tags").doc("favorites")["value"] > 5;

               
              }
          ),

builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

    return Column(children: snapshot.map((e) => PostCard(post: e)).toList());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you is that create a new `collection "tags"`

And stream that collection..

```
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tags").where('favorites', isGreaterThan: 5).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return Column(children: snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => PostCard(post: e)).toList());
      },
    );
```